# Visible domain redirection using DNS CNAME

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, cname

Hi I'm a new to this stuff. could you please teach me this.

We are redirecting the domain using DNS.
For example
we have a domain  called www.olddomain.com and www.newdomain.com
If we access access the www.newdomain.com means we can able to acces the application.
If we access the www.olddomain.com also we can able to access the same application because we did redirection through DNS CNAME.But teh adress bar still showing the www.olddomain.com

We want the addres bar also to be changed to the new domain www.newdomain.com
I Hope it can be done through the some redirction in apache. Could you please teach me how to do.

If we access both the domain name it should go to the same application (its happening by the DNS CNAME) along with that i want the adress bar also to be changed to www.newdomain.com if though we access www.olddomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache's [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and, for heaven's sake, find someone you can pay for doing that kind of stuff for you.